# Failed to start ddev-ssh-agent container: Permission denied on socket

Tags: ddev

When I start a DDEV-Local project, I get "Failed to start ddev-ssh-agent", and when I use `docker logs ddev-ssh-agent` I see

> Running socat UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/.ssh-agent/proxy-socket,perm=0666,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/.ssh-agent/socket
>   unix_listener: cannot bind to path /tmp/.ssh-agent/socket: Permission denied
>   2020/04/29 14:50:25 socat[16] E bind(5, {AF=1 "/tmp/.ssh-agent/proxy-socket"}, 30): Permission denied

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Use this sequence to fix this exact problem:

```
ddev poweroff
docker volume rm ddev-ssh-agent_dot_ssh ddev-ssh-agent_socket_dir
ddev start
```

That will repair/replace the docker volumes that store the ssh-agent socket, and seems to resolve this problem.

If you know what sequence of events might have caused this, please comment or open an [issue](https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues) to explain. It is mostly likely caused by using root privileges with ddev, but ddev actively tries to prevent that.